# User won't auto save in View, but does in Admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, view

Building a form to let users submit posts as well as an image. My model has a text field, image, publish date, and author field. Publish Date and Author auto save without any user input. It works on the admin side with admin.py. However, when displaying this through a view, it is not working. Why?

```
#models.py
    class Question(models.Model):
    text            = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'movie_poster')
    pub_date        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
             model = Question
             exclude = ('author', 'pub_date')
#views.py
def add_question(request):
     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
     if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)   
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
    else:
        form = QuestionForm
        return render_to_response("qanda/add_question.html", {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

#add_question.html
{% block content %}

<div class="loginform">
    <h1> Add Movie:</h1>
    <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Add" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = "next" value = "{{ next|escape }}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save_model` is not magic that works everywhere just by being there. We'll need to customize the form:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, user=None, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        q = super(QuestionForm, self).save(commit=False)
        q.author = user
        if commit:
            q.save()
        return q

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('author', 'pub_date')

def add_question(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(user=request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        return render_to_response("qanda/add_question.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Changed the view to what you have, and still getting this error : 'qanda_question.author_id may not be NULL'

Comment: I am, in add_question.html if user is authenticated, it displays {{ user.username }} and I'm seeing my username.

Comment: awesome, worked. although i did have in my model, had to change q= super(QuestionForm).save(commit = False) to q = super(QuestionForm, self).save(commit = False). Thanks again!